# how to run two widget on same time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

I am using the package to show the pdf but the loading part of the pdf is in Chinese and is not customizable so I want to show a widget over a widget when the loading part is in progress I want to show my own loading dialog for half of the second over that loading bar
[package that i am using](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)
can someone help please
**my code**

```
 body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: FileView(controller: widget.controller)),
    ],
  ),
```

widget.controller is the getting path of pdf

Comment: Look into Overlays: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 `Visibility` Widgets inside a Stack and toggle the `Visibility` based on the requirement

```
Stack
|_Visiblity
 |_ Loading Widget     set visible to false once loading
|_Visibility
 |_ Pdf Widget          set visible to true once loading
```